# How to generate all mutan with X number of mutation for a given RNA sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, mutation

I want to find all the possible mutan from a DNA / RNA sequence with x mutation.

I made the code for getting all the mutant with 1 mutation, but I don't know how to generalise it for x number of mutation.

```
def generateAllMutan(baseSeq):
    base= ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
    mutantList = []
    for i in range(len(baseSeq)):
        for nuc in base:
            if nuc != baseSeq[i]:
                seqName = "name" + str(i+1) + "_" + baseSeq[i] + "_to_" + nuc
                mutedSeq = baseSeq[0:i] + nuc + baseSeq[i++1:]
                mutantList.append(SeqRecord(Seq(mutedSeq), id= seqName, name="", description=""))

    return     mutantList
```

I would like this function to work with any number of desire mutation
like `def generateAllMutan(baseSeq, nbMutation):`

But I have no idea how to do it efficiently.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing against the specified number of matches: `n`

```
def function(s, n):
  for x in range(len(s)):
    for a in b:
      if a != s[x] and count <= n:
        #code
        count +=1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but, except if I miss understand, it doesn't really answer my question... 
To be more precise, what I want, is a DNA / RNA sequence and a number of mutation as inpute, and, as output, a list of all the possible mutans that have the  precise number of mutation.